# Using python and xlrd to a word in excel sheet and output sentence to txt file

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm wondering how to use xlrd with python to find a specific word in an excel file and then output the sentence that contains that word.

Answer (score 0):

Python in general has very good documentation on [how to work with files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) and [how to look for info in data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

xlrd has also very good [documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966), so I definitely recommend checking that out.

Regarding your question, please have a look at [Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask questions.  It's generally welcome when you pass some code with the question.

For the answer, here is quick example:

```
import xlrd

try:
    excel_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls")
except Exception as e:
    print e

sheet0 = excel_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

new_file = open("test.file","w")

for row_idx in xrange(sheet0.nrows):
    row = sheet0.row_values(row_idx)
    if "Epic" in row:
        new_file.write(",".join(str(value) for value in row))
        new_file.write("\n")

new_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. But for some reason it only matches if you put the whole sentence in to look for. For example if i search for "Hot" it doesn't find it when the sentence "Hot Edge-Cold Core storage architecture with DSSD" exists in the file.

Comment: In this example I am iterating through rows in first sheet in excel file. Each row is represented as a list of string items, where each item is one column in row. So if you have sentences in columns then you will want to add checking on each column.